# Flutter project in Android Studio gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, androidx

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat' has different version for the compile (1.0.1) and runtime (1.0.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


BUILD FAILED in 5s

*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.

*******************************************************************************************
Finished with error: 
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below inside your `build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { it ->
        if (it.requested.group == 'androidx.appcompat'
              && !it.requested.name.contains('appcompat') ) {
           it.useVersion "1.0.2"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Or

Change `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` to version **1.0.2** inside your `dependencies {}` block.